# Transfer sql server 2000 database to sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have a database on my Virtual PC running SQL server 2000. I want to transfer this to SQL server 2008 on my regular enviroment. I've tried to detach the database and moved it via the shared folder and then attached it in my SQL server management studio. But it will not complete the attachement and i get this error message:

> "An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   Unable to open the physical file
>   "C:\Database.MDF". Operating system
>   error 5: "5(failed to retrieve text
>   for this error. Reason: 15105)".
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)"

What faults 'am I doing?

Best regards,
Wayne

Answer (score 3):

Error 5 is "access denied". No rights? Read-Only?

BTW: "C:\" is a really bad place for a mdf file. It might very well be that your SQL-Server service account has no rights there. Try putting the mdf file into SQL Servers default data directory.

Edit: Also, I'm not quite sure if detach/attach will work from 2000 to 2008. A backup/restore should work though.

Answer (score 2):

try to do backup of your 2000 database and then restore it in 2008